# If there exist an irreducible representation, an equivalent representation to it would also be irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Suppose ρ is an irreducible representation of a group and φ be an equivalent representation of it. Then is φ irreducible. Also does a similar argument holds for decomposability and complete reducibility. And does either of the cases implies the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the above properties should be preserved under equivalence. The key fact is that if we have a linear isomorphism $\phi: V \to V'$, then we get an isomorphism $GL(V) \cong GL(V')$, given by sending $A : V \to V$ to the composition $\phi \circ A \circ \phi^{-1}$, which is a linear transformation $V' \to V'$.

Now if $\phi, \rho$ are equivalent, and $\rho$ is reducible with proper subrepresentation $(\rho', W)$, then compose with the isomorphisms $V \cong V'$ and $GL(V) \cong GL(V')$ to find a reduction for $\phi$, and use the definition of equivalence of $\phi, \rho$ to check that all the properties still hold.

Comment: So basically it is saying that the subspaces remain the same under transformation?

Comment: The subspaces don't need to stay the same, they just need to move with the isomorphism $V \to V'$. Take $G = \mathbb{Z}/2$, and let $\phi$ be the representation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $1$ maps to the transformation that swaps the $x$ and $y$ axes while preserving $z$.  This is reducible, with the $xy$ plane one subspace and $z$ axis the other. Now let $\rho$ be the representation where $1$ swaps the $y$ and $z$ axes. The fixed subspaces of $\rho$ are the $yz$ plane and the $x$ axis. But $\phi$ and $\rho$ are equivalent because we could change coordinates to turn one into the other.

Answer (score 1):

Any module property preserved by isomorphism will correspond to a representation property preserved by equivalence.  Irreducibility (simplicity) and complete-reducibility (semisimplicity) are both preserved by module isomorphisms, so yes.